# JQuery - pushing elements to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following working code:

```
    var eachLine;
    var newArray =[];
    $.each(eachLine, function(){
        allWordsArray.push($.trim(this));
    });
```

But when I try to modify the above the above code like below: I am passing the variable to a function which returns a variable.

```
      var eachLine;
      var newArray =[];
      $.each(eachLine, function(){
         var stem = stemmer($.trim(this));
         allWordsArray.push(stem);
      });
```

It is throwing me a type error later in some other function - saying not an object while passing an object.

Could some one please point out what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post `stemmer` code!

Comment: `"a type error later in some other function"` - Maybe you could be more specific?  "There's some error somewhere else" isn't really a question we can answer.  What's the error?  Where does it happen?  When you debug this, where does the behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: `eachLine` is `undefined`

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir  Thank you, its the porter stemmer algorithm thats used. https://github.com/kristopolous/Porter-Stemmer/blob/master/PorterStemmer1980.js

Comment: Can you post a complete example with all the variables defined?

Answer (score 0):

### $.each() : A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1.

`eachLine` is not an object, `$.each` requires an object or array to iterate which return index,key,value in callback function.